# pushViewController not working after back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

For my code structure:

On AppDelegate, I declared 4 UINavigationController with their own root UIViewController for my UITabBar.

I created one custom UIViewController as template, in where my other UIViewControllers are sub-class.

On my template:
I have my rightBarButtonItem to show current user profile.

```
// public method added on template
- (void) goToProfile {
    NSLog(@"going through...");
    ProfileViewController *ctrl = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
}
```

For my leftBarButtonItem:

```
- (void) goBack {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

First click on the `rightBarButtonItem`, works fine. If I click the `leftBarButtonItem` to go back then re-click the `rightBarButtonItem`, it won't work anymore.

In addition, I have a button on one of my UIViewController that is calling the public method `goToProfile`. And that works fine.

Comment: any error message you get on console?

Comment: need to see a little more code

Comment: Try [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES]; to push ViewController

Comment: Updated my post for `self.navigationController`, typo. I will try to post more code. No error message but if I put `NSLog(@"entered")`, it is being printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing or popping with UINavigation controllers of UITabBar

Else show UINavigation Controllers inside UITab Bar..i.e; Is Profile View controller is part of UITab bar or not..

Then you need to change the index of tab bar as below

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;//if profile is first tab

ProfileViewController *ctrl = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: I tried this but did not work. When your code was implemented, first click brought me to selectedIndex, second click brought to the pushed controller and if I go back and hit the button again, original issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I got help from my co-worker. The approach is something similar to @Vidhyanand900 answer. I hope this will help others in the future.

```
tabbarSelectedIndex = 1; // profile tab index

ProfileViewController *ctrl = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [_appDelegate.mainTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabbarSelectedIndex];
[navController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];

self.mainTabBarController.selectedIndex = tabbarSelectedIndex;
```